# mysqil_real_escape_string() error I can't fix

Tags: php

Although the item is successfully added to the database, I'm not sure that I'm executing the mysql_real_escape_string() function correctly and, thus, getting the error. Any help is appreciated.

> Success!
>
> Warning: array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an array in /home/site4/public_html/lab/mailing_list_dev_1-0/mailing_list_add.php on line 32
>
> Thanks for signing up!

Here's the code in question...

```
<?php
// connects the database access information this file
include("mailing_list_include.php");

// the following code relates to mailing list signups only
if (($_POST) && ($_POST["action"] == "sub")) {

if ($_POST["email"] == "") {
        header("Location: mailing_list_add.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        // connect to database
        doDB();
    
        // filtering out anything that isn't an email address
        if ( filter_var(($_POST["email"]), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)  == TRUE) {
            echo 'Success!';
        } else {
            echo 'Invalid Email Address';
            exit;
        }
        
        // check that the email is in the database
        emailChecker($_POST["email"]);
    
        // get number of results and do action
        if (mysqli_num_rows($check_res) < 1) {
            // free result
            mysqli_free_result($check_res); 
        
            // cleans all input variables at once
            $email = array_map("mysqli_real_escape_string", ($_POST["email"]));
            
            // add record
            $add_sql =  "INSERT INTO subscribers (email)
                        VALUES('".$_POST["email"]."')";
            $add_res =  mysqli_query($mysqli, $add_sql)
                        or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
            $display_block = "<p>Thanks for signing up!</p>";
        
            // close connection to mysql
            mysqli_close($mysqli);
        } else {
            // print failure message
            $display_block = "You're email address, ".$_POST["email"].", is already subscribed.";
    }
}
}

?>
<html>
<?php echo "$display_block";?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're treating `$_POST['email']` as an array, which it probably ins't.

If you only intended to escape `email`, do

```
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConn, $_POST['email']);
```

Then in your `INSERT` statement, use the escaped `$email` instead of `$_POST['email']`

```
$add_sql =  "INSERT INTO subscribers (email) VALUES('$email')";
```

Comment: Tried the line $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
 and got this error : "Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/site4/public_html/lab/mailing_list_dev_1-0/mailing_list_add.php on line 32"

Comment: @Andy Sorry, I didn't notice you were using `mysqli` instead of the older `mysql` functions.  You have to pass the link resource, created when you connected to the database.  I put in `$dbConn`, change to whatever it really is inside your `doDB()` function.

Comment: Wow, awesome help, thanks. And I also have a similar script for removing an address, do I need to apply the same filter for that as well? Or does removing something not add something to the mysql so can't do any damage? Also, is this sufficient to protect against malicious code in your opinion?

Comment: @Andy In this script, since your only database call is that `INSERT` and its only variable is `$email`, this is sufficiently protected against SQL injection.  You MUST also do it for your delete script, and any other script in which you embed user-input PHP vars into SQL strings.

Answer (score 2):

`array_map()` is meant for arrays. If all you have is a single value then just call the function directly.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one bug, here:

```
// Does not work because $_POST["email"] is a string, not an array
$email = array_map("mysqli_real_escape_string", ($_POST["email"]));
```

This looks like something you adapted from code that was working, but right now it's broken. You probably wanted something like this:

```
$post = array_map("mysqli_real_escape_string", $_POST["email"]);
```

after which you can use `$post["email"]` safely, as it has been escaped.

Of course escaping everything inside `$_POST` is possibly not the best way to go about this. There's still the mundane but spot-on way to consider:

```
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

Comment: Appreciate the guidance. I did adapt it from something else, just trying to break things apart to see how they work.

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently not mysqli_real_escape_string problem but array_map() problem. Or rather misuse of the latter one.

However, you will face  mysqli_real_escape_string() problem as soon as you solves this one.
To solve this latter your `doDB()` function have to return connection id, which you have to use with every mysqli_* function.

```
$conn = doDB();
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["email"]);
```

thus you will have all your [listed] problems solved but I believe that emailChecker <s>will</s> may cause the same kind of problem of inexistent $check_res variable. Instea d of which such a function apparently have to return just a boolean and used like

```
if (!emailChecker($_POST["email"])) {
```